# Is there something like Global.asax file for ASP web site?

Tags: asp-classic, exception, global-asax

I have a big web site build on ASP. Is there possibility to handle all exceptions in one place? Like Global.asax in ASP.NET application?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you've got an answer already to the question you actually asked.  However your requirement from the content of your question is "How do I centrally handle an error".

So the solution to your problem (although not an answer to the question actually posed) is:

Use a custom error page at the applications root folder level that handles the status code 500.100.

You can determine the error using `Server.GetLastError()`, which returns an [IASPError](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_error.asp) from which you can gather error details.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is the global.asa file and No, it doesn't have the global OnException event like asp.net has.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you can use a global.asa file in the root to handle site wide instances.

See ["The Global.asa file" for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_globalasa.asp).